# ¿Puedo enviar un BLOB a un input file desde Javascript?

Tags: javascript, blob

Tengo un sitio web en el que graba un vídeo, y lo que hace es crear un *BLOB* y luego lo manda a una *URL* del servidor con `URL.createObjectURL()`. Pero necesito guardar ese *BLOB* en *MySQL*, así que intentaba mandar el *BLOB* a un `input` de tipo file para luego cuando lo llame de *PHP* sacarlo de ahí.

Código:

```
function makeLink()
{
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
    , url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    , li = document.createElement('li')
    , mt = document.createElement(media.tag)
    , hf = document.createElement('a')
    ,contenedor=document.createElement('input')

   li.setAttribute("id","li");
   contenedor.setAttribute("id","video2");
   contenedor.setAttribute("name","video2");
   contenedor.setAttribute("type","file");
   contenedor.setAttribute("value",chunks);

   mt.controls = true;
   mt.src = url;
   hf.href = url; 
}
```

Comment: Por razones de seguridad no se puede modificar el archivo de un input file mediante codigo

Comment: Y sabes depronto de que otra manera puedo mandar el blob para guardarlo en mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puesto que ya tienes los datos contenidos en un [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) no necesitas usar un campo tipo archivo `<input type="file">` para enviarlo, puedes hacerlo en un campo oculto `<input type="hidden">`, para hacerlo debes usar la [Web API FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

A continuacion un ejemplo de las modificaciones que debes realizar a tu codigo:

```
function makeLink()
{
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
    , url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    , li = document.createElement('li')
    , mt = document.createElement(media.tag)
    , hf = document.createElement('a')
    , contenedor=document.createElement('input')

   li.setAttribute("id","li");
   contenedor.setAttribute("id","video2");
   contenedor.setAttribute("name","video2");
   contenedor.setAttribute("type","hidden");

   // Creamos la instancia -> Web API FileReader()
   var reader = new FileReader();

   // Definimos el Evento onload()
   reader.onload = function(e) {

     // convertimos el resultado de la carga a base64
     // para poder transportar los datos al Servidor
     var fileInBase64 = btoa(e.target.result);

     // Cargamos el Resultado al contenedor del Formulario
     contenedor.setAttribute("value", fileInBase64);
   };

   // Ahora comenzamos a leer el contenido del Blob
   // y lo pasamos en formato binario
   reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);

   mt.controls = true;
   mt.src = url;
   hf.href = url; 
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias! :):)

Comment: Es que no podía ser de otra manera, me complace verte ayudado, Saludos!!!;))...